# How do I make a POST request to roblox using discord.js?

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js, roblox

I recently made a discord bot and would like to know how I can integrate it to Roblox (beginner in web development).

[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Usw.png)

**Here’s my attempt at fixing this (got messy)**:

```js
if (command == "robloxmessage") {
  if (args[0] && args.length <= 1) {

    if (!startedServer) {
      console.log("Server started at http://localhost:8000")
      message.channel.send("Initializing remote server.")
      server = app.listen(port)
      message.channel.send("Initialized remote server.")
      console.log("Server listening on port.")
      startedServer = true;
      try {
        app.post('/post', (request, response) => { //send a post request to the url
          response.send(`${args[0]}`) //send (post)
          console.log(request.body) //log roblox response
          setTimeout(function() {
            server.close();
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^
          }, 3000)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Roblox Event command error ${error}`)
        message.reply(`Try again or contact Johnapolitan#7935`)
      }
      console.log(`${startedServer}`)
    } else {

      const sockets = new Set();

      server.on('connection', (socket) => {
        sockets.add(socket);

        server.once('close', () => {
          sockets.delete(socket);
        });
      });

      /**
       * Forcefully terminates HTTP server.
       */
```

```js
const close = (callback) => {
  for (const socket of sockets) {
    socket.destroy();

    sockets.delete(socket);
  }

  server.close(callback);
};
try {
  app.post('/post', (request, response) => { //send a post request to the url
    response.send(`${args[0]}`) //send (post)
    console.log(request.body) //log roblox response
  })

} catch (error) {
  console.log(`Roblox Event command error ${error}`)
  message.reply(`Try again or contact Johnapolitan#7935`)
}
}
} else {
  return message.channel.send(`Please provide the proper arguments. Use !help to see them.`);
}
}
```

Already tried: Forcing the server to close and using server.close()

To be honest, the code is at the point where it needs to be rewritten so if you’ve done this before I can just it again of your response.

Answer (score 0):

For simple post requests I recommend using an HTTP request library like Fetch. Fetch would make your life tons easier and lets you use a lot less code.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Answer (score 0):

For POST, GET or any other HTTP requests, I would recommend you to use axios

https://npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.